# Checking whether host already joined an agora.io session

Tags: agora.io

we integrated agora.io into our app that allows students to join a video live-class with their teacher. When students try to join the live-class before their teacher, they should be notified accordingly. Is there a way to check whether a host has joined an agora.io session yet or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this RESTFul api to see if a specific user is in a channel: https://docs.agora.io/en/Audio%20Broadcast/dashboard_restful_live?platform=All_Platforms#get-a-user-role-in-the-channel-get. You need to pass the teacher's id and channel name in the parameter and the api will return if this user is in that channel.